# Add new functionality to article form from component

Tags: joomla, components

I developed a component for Joomla 2.5 that allow user to import videos from their computer to their website.

I need to know if I could, from my component, alter the article creation form in order to add new functionalities such as adding a video to the article? In short if I could add buttons for example to implement this behavior.

Comment: You need to make a plugin if you want to add additional functionality to you article manager.

Comment: So I can not access to other module through straightforward functions like Wordpress or Drupal does? Wow developing joomla's components sucks :/

Comment: If you need to shows your video inside the article in front end then you can make a module ,fetch your data on to it and make a position where you want to show your module and call that module.

Comment: I already developed a function called inside my module that creates articles with videos inside. But I wanted to allow administrator to add videos during article creation...